# Windows form freezes when bound combobox selection is made

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, freeze

I have a pretty simple form that brings up a certain record when the "caseNumber" is selected from the combobox.  Although after a selection is made within the combobox, it will freeze the entire form on the record selected.  I can't click on any other text boxes or buttons.  I have to stop the debugger.  No errors are thrown.  I've read where this has happened to others, but no answers to the problem, that I can find.

There is no code behind it so far, as the form is bound to a dataset and should just bring up the rest of the information once the caseNumber is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the "Selected Value" dropbox to "none" on the data binding menu for the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Under DataBindings, go to Advanced and make sure DataSource update mode is on NOne

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times this happens because there is a problem in the binding. Are you sure it's not binding the text value of the control(the combobobox) to the data?

The correct way to bind (under DataBindings, Advanced) was to bind it to the SelectedValue instead of Text.

Please let us know a little bit more how your combobox is binded.

Comment: I changed the binding to "SelectedValue", like you said, but it still freezes after using the combobox.

Comment: I have it bound as "SelectedValue" = CaseBindingSource - caseNumber

Comment: Try SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue. See if that clears things up.

Comment: That threw an error: "Cannot set column 'caseNumber'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column."

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting [CausesValidation] to FALSE in the combobox properties.